# How to recover old commit messages after accidentally exiting vim editor?

Tags: git, vim, command-line, git-commit

Using: Windows 10, command-line with git commands

I was using git (following this tutorial: https://help.github.com/en/github/committing-changes-to-your-project/changing-a-commit-message) to change some old messages to commit messages to add something to each one. I used the command: `git rebase -i HEAD~10` and this showed the last 10 commits. After naming each 'pick' with 'reword' to the commit messages I wanted, I was not sure how to exit and save. Therefore, I decided to click the cross button on the command prompt and when I checked git log again on my project, all the last 10 commits were gone. How can I recover them?

Comment: Do note one of the most referenced qs of all time is how to exit vim. Also see [vi.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open bash and go again to the repository directory. You should be at a "rebase x/x" state as pointed by the blue words at the end of the line.

You can use then "git rebase --abort" to return to the point before executing the interactive rebase command.

(Source: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---abort)

Comment: I am using command prompt on Windows 10. Would you know how to do it with that?

Comment: The "git status" command should show you if you are in a rebasing state. Then you can apply the rebase abort command.

Answer (score 1):

1. Run `git status` to check if you branch is also in the `rebase` process. If you have something like `(develop|REBASE-i)`, you just execute `git rebase --abort` to abort the rebase.
2. If you're not in the `rebase` process, you can recover from the reflog suppose you've not delete them. 
   Use `git reflog` to find the commit hashcode. Then recover it with `git reset --hard hashcode`